# How to couple 4" round corrugated downspout to plain round

Tags: plumbing, drainage, gutters, rain, downspout

I'd like to connect a 4" plain round downspout filter to an existing 4" round corrugated downspout.  Do I need a specific type of coupling to do that, or will the 4" corrugated fit inside the plain?  I see that the corrugated is already wedged into the 4" iron storm drain below.  BTW there is a stack of corrugated above it going for 3 stories so not sure if structurally cutting parts of it out would just bring the weight of the downspout stack above it down on your fingers so not sure if there is any kind of bracing or weight considerations to be had while putting in the desired filter in the middle of that pipe at about chest level.

[image]

And this is what I'm contemplating splicing into the downspout

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use a 5-Blade hand Sheet Metal Crimper to reduce the end of the pipe so it will fit into the drain. This is a common tool and not too expensive.  [image]

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge there is no specific fitting to connect the metal drain pipe to the round drain. (the black drain looks like ABS plastic and not iron.) You could use the rubber Fernco fittings. A concern I have is the picture depicts leaves being separated from rainwater, with the water being discharged at 90deg. to the side and the leaves falling vertically. If this is the set up the rainwater will be dumped right next to the building and the leaves will eventually clog the drain pipe.  Perhaps you need an offset in the system to let the leaves dump on the ground and the water be directed to the drain.
Regarding the weight of the corrugated downspout, I don't think it is very heavy and it should be anchored to the building in a couple of spots.

Comment: I would add a rain barrel to catch the diverted water, and feels like iron when I knock on it with my hand. Not sure about the leaves ... does that mean without water to take it down, it's more likely to clog?